# Pandas: Group by date and the median of another variable

Tags: python, pandas

This is a demo example of my DataFrame. The full DataFrame has multiple additional variables and covers 6 months of data.

```
sentiment     date
1             2015-05-26 18:58:44
0.9           2015-05-26 19:57:31
0.7           2015-05-26 18:58:24
0.4           2015-05-27 19:17:34
0.6           2015-05-27 18:46:12
0.5           2015-05-27 13:32:24
1             2015-05-28 19:27:31
0.7           2015-05-28 18:58:44
0.2           2015-05-28 19:47:34
```

I want to group the DataFrame by just the day of the `date` column, but at the same time aggregate the median of the `sentiment` column.

Everything I have tried with `groupby`, the `dt` accessor and `timegrouper` has failed.

I want to return a pandas DataFrame not a GroupBy object.

The date column is `M8[ns]`

The sentiment column `float64`

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You fortunately have the tools you need listed in your question.

```
In [61]: df.groupby(df.date.dt.date)[['sentiment']].median()
Out[61]:
            sentiment
2015-05-26        0.9
2015-05-27        0.5
2015-05-28        0.7
```

Answer (score 4):

I would do this :

```
df['date'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x : x.date())
df = df.groupby('date').agg({'sentiment':np.median}).reset_index()
```

You first replace the datetime column with the date.
Then you perform the groupby+agg operation.

Answer (score 3):

I would do this, because you can do multiple aggregations (like median, mean, min, max, etc.) on multiple columns at the same time:

```
df.groupby(df.date.dt.date).agg({'sentiment': ['median']})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get any number of metrics using one group by and .agg() function
1) create new column extracting date.
2) Use groupy by and apply numpy.median,numpy.mean etc

```
import pandas as pd
x = [[1,'2015-05-26 18:58:44'],
     [0.9,'2015-05-26 19:57:31']]
t = pd.DataFrame(x,columns = ['a','b'])
t.b = pd.to_datetime(t['b'])
t['datex'] = t['b'].dt.date


t.groupby(['datex']).agg({
    'a': np.median
})
```

Output -

```
datex   
2015-05-26  0.95
```